# how to determine transient and recurrent state from transition matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I wonder how can I determine the transient and recurrent state from transition matrix ? I mean if I have 10 states It would be very hard to draw diagram for them so how to analyse the matrix?
     For example consider :
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.1 & 0.2 & 0.7 & 0 \\
0.7 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.1 \\
0.6 & 0.4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Can anyone tell me how to approach this problem I only want to know how to look at transition matrix and identify transient and recurrent states?

Thanks.

Comment: *Draw a picture*. Only those places in the matrix with a nonzero entry matter.

Comment: I know this was 4 states problem what if I have 8 states then drawing picture is not very efficient method. I am looking for another method to identify states by solely looking at entries of matrix.

Comment: You may use the  free  software MCQueue that can be downloaded from http://personal.vu.nl/h.c.tijms/   The module for state classification is based on a classical paper of Fox and Landi in Commun. ACM 11 (1968), p. 619-621

Comment: Thanks I am looking for method to approach these types of problem later like using this method in the exam,...

Answer (score 1):

The formal way to do this and as defined in the book Introduction to Probability Models by Sheldon Ross is:

A state $i$ is recurrent if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{ii}^n = \infty$

A state $i$ is transient if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{ii}^n < \infty$

You can also define this as:

A state $i$ where $i \in S$ is said to be recurrent if $f_i$ = $P$(ever returns to $i$| starts in $i$) = 1

A state $j$ where $j \in S$ is said to be recurrent if $f_j$ = $P$(ever returns to $j$| starts in $j$) < 1

You would need to do this for all states in your matrix and solve it.